# Compact space X is totally disconnected if and only if C(X) is generated by its projections

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, operator-theory, c-star-algebras

If $X$ is compact, show that $X$ is totally disconnected if and only if $C(X)$ as a C*-algebra is generated by its projections.

My attempt: Suppose $X$ is totally disconnected, then $X=\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$. In this case clearly $C(X)$ is generated by the family of projections $\{\chi_{x_i} ; i\in I\}$.

Conversely, suppose $X$ is not totally disconnected, so there is a subset $Y$ of $X$ such that $Y$ is a connected component and it has at least two points.

If $X\not\subset \Bbb C$, then there is a compact subset $X'$ of $\Bbb C$ such that $C(X)$ is an $*-$ isomorphism onto $C(X')$. Thus we can suppose $X\subset \Bbb C$.

Clearly $id_Y$ is a generator for C(X) and is not a projection which is a contradiction.

Please check my attempt and allow me to know your opinion about that. Thanks.

Comment: The Cantor set is a totally disconnected compact set that's not finite.

Comment: @MikeMiller : I changed that. Is it correct now?

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Projections are  elements $f$ so that $f^2=f$. For $f\in C(X)$ this is equivalent to  $f$ takes the values $0$ and $1$. A continuous functions $f \colon X\to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(X)\subset \{0,1\}$ gets us a partition of $X$ into two disjoint closed sets $f^{-1}(0)$ and $f^{-1}(1)$

What does it mean that a family of functions generates $C(X)$. It means that it contains the constants and separates the points ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Is your hint about converse direction? I just can see $X$ is disconnect, but not totally disconnect.

Comment: Right, you want to show that for every two distinct points there exists a function that takes different values at these points. Moreover, the function has to be a projection. So the points end up one in $f^{-1}(0)$, the other in $f^{-1}(1)$.